# Two DNS for one IP address

Tags: dns

There is a Windows Domain Server and DNS installed on it. 
There are users in LAN and domain name is `example.local` . 
Web server with IP address 192.168.10.124 is written in that Windows DNS server like this:

```
 name_of_web   Host(A) 192.168.10.124
```

When users in that LAN type `name_of_web` in their browsers, webpage opens. 
DNS is working, no problem. Hostname of this web server is: `name_of_web.example.local` 

 
Now I installed DNS server in Linux. 
My aim: to advertise this new DNS server to my branch offices. 
For example, when staff of branch office types `name_of_web` in browser,
webpage should open. 
Staff of branch office has to add my DNS server ip address to network configurations, and I should open access to my DNS server in router, that is clear.

 
According to these, I have some questions: 

1. In Linux DNS server, what do I have to write in the domain name? I mean, what will be my zone name? 
2. How should I write A record for web server in right way?

It means I will have 2 DNS servers, and now web server is in 1st `example.local` domain. 
PS: ip address of new Linux DNS server is 192.168.10.127.

Comment: Which exactly DNS server did you install (there are many of them)? Did you try to read its documentation?

Comment: Additonally, in stead of manually managing the zone on two different boxes you should set up a master/slave relationship so when one is updated it updates the other.  Easy to do in `bind` - but you've not given us enough info (ie, what DNS server software you are using ,etc)

Comment: @rush, I installed bind

Comment: @ivanivan, I use bind. Master DNS is in Windows Server 2016, and Slave DNS will be in Linux with bind. How to do?